# Web Deploy Type Access Failures

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I have an ASP.NET web application that formerly published just fine to several locations. Now when I try to publish or package the application from Visual Studio, regardless of method (i.e., through the Build menu, through One-Click Publish, or the project's context menu), the operation fails with the following error:

> Web deployment task failed. (Attempt by method 'Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.VSMSDeployDriverInCmd.LogTrace (Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentTraceEventArgs)' to access type 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterEventArgs' failed.)

Which doesn't give much guidance on how to fix it. I have reinstalled Visual Studio and Web Deploy to no avail. Tried disabling and even uninstalling my Visual Studio plugins - nothing.

Can someone give insight into the cause of this message and how to fix it? Or at least how to diagnose what the real problem is?

Comment: I should note that a web search for specific terms in the message returns only a single, unrelated MSDN forums result. Searching for generic terms turns up a large number of completely unrelated issues. Either no one has had this issue before (unlikely), or they haven't posted it anywhere that's easy to find...